# Root page not working when redirecting

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-routing

I am using the below code to redirect to the root page.

```
return Redirect::to('/');
```

I have defined the home page route as below.

```
Route::get('/', 'PagesController@home');
```

When the page is redirect to root page, I expect the url to be http://localhost/crafts/public/ but its http://localhost/crafts/public/home. I am not sure where does that /home gets added. I have the home function defined in the PagesController file.

This is the PagesController section.

```
public function home()
{
  return view('home');
}
```

All other routes shown below work fine except the main route.

```
Route::get('about', 'PagesController@about');
Route::get('contact', 'PagesController@contact');
Route::get('auth/{provider}', 'Auth\AuthController@login');
Route::get('auth/{provider}/callback', 'Auth\AuthController@callback');
```

Please explain what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Please show all your routes.

Comment: Edited the question to add all routes.

Comment: This is weird. My guess is `RedirectIfAuthenticated` middleware kicks in before your redirect attempt.

Comment: is it possible that your `.htaccess` file adds it? I know sometimes Apache adds an `index` if the request ends with a `/`. http://davidwalsh.name/directory-index-homepage-htaccess. An easy test is to redirect to '/public' instead of '/'. You should update your route accordingly.

Comment: @CrackingTheCode: It's not in .htaccess. I have checked that.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at

```
app/http/Middleware/RedirectIfAuthenticated.php
```

it has this code:

```
/**
 * Handle an incoming request.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  \Closure  $next
 * @return mixed
 */
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if ($this->auth->check()) {
        return redirect('/home');
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

So when you are using Redirect, it probably authenticates first which then calls the handle function above which is clearly adding a /home

I do notice one thing that you said you are using Laravel-5 in the question label. In that case, replace the Redirect code with:

```
return redirect('/');
```

The syntax `Redirect::To` is for version 4.x or earlier.

Comment: Great.. Where would this redirect("/") exactly come in the controller? I am using a view in the home controller to render it.

Comment: `redirect()` is a helper